# jQuery addClass click and removeClass when click again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a box without color. if the box is being `click()` it will `addClass('.red')` to make it red, and if click again the box color change to blue. they change alternatively. and I don't know how to make it.

### Code

#### HTML

```
<div class='box'></div>
```

#### CSS

```
.box {          
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;    
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}

.red {
    background: red;
}

.blue {
    background: blue;
}
```

### Javascript

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('red');
});
```

[link of jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XQE3J/)

Comment: Edited your jsFiddle. Please see this link http://jsfiddle.net/XQE3J/7/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try with `toggleClass` like

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("red");
});
```

If you want to toggle `2 classes` `red` and `blue` then use like

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("red blue");
});
```

Comment: yes this is what i want sir.. you got it. but i also want to change color from white to red and blue

Comment: Shouldn't the second parameter be a bool?

Comment: Sorry in hurry iam not going well..See my final ans now

Comment: See my answer for toggling red and blue.

Comment: only change to color blue

Comment: what if i want to toggle 2 or more class at the same time? like red class with bold class toggle and blue class with italic class?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change from white to red, and then red to blue, you can't use `toggleClass()`. You'd have to write some simple conditions to decide which class to add:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('blue')) {
        $this.removeClass();
    } else if ($this.hasClass('red')) {
        $this.removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
    } else {
        $this.addClass('red');
    }
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pRFaA/1/)

If you only want to switch between the classes red and blue, just add one of the classes to the markup, so that you can toggle between them:

```
<div class="blue">Hello World!</div>
```

Then just use toggleClass():

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('red blue');
});
```

#### [Here's another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pRFaA/2/)

Comment: it's really great answer :) Thanks for your help .

Answer (score 2):

use [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
.hasClass()
```

to check the assigned class, try something like this:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    if($('div').hasClass('red')) {       
        $(this).removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
    }
    else{
        $(this).removeClass('blue').addClass('red');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XQE3J/4/)

```
  $('div').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('red'))
    {
        $(this).addClass('blue').removeClass('red');
    }
    else
    {
       $(this).addClass('red').removeClass('blue');
    }
  });
```

[Refer this API documentation for more about toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: You have an extra closing bracket for your `.blue`.

Comment: @JGallardo Where? I don't see

Comment: in your demo. You have an extra closing bracket on the blue and actually the class is defined twice `.blue
{
    background:blue;
}
}

.blue {
    background: blue;
}`